# Couchbase Server not returning CORS Header to XMLHttpRequest object

Tags: javascript, server, cors, couchbase

We have Couchbase Server installed on a VM. I have include the tags:

```
 [cors]
 methods: GET
 origins: *

 [httpd]
 enable_cors = true
```

in our local.ini file located at: D:\Couchbase\etc\couchdb. In PostMan I am able to execute: http:/xxxx:8093/query/service?statement= select  member  from  `edc` where member.general_info.member_id= '11111' and see a valid response returned. But when trying to request with JS in our web application we are blocked. Our JS looks like:

```
var xhReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhReq.open("GET", "xxxx:8093/query/service?statement=select member from `edc` where member.general_info.member_aces_id= '11111'", true);
xhReq.onload = function() {
  console.log('Response from CORS request ' + xhReq.responseText);
};
xhReq.onerror = function() {
  console.log('Woops, there was an error ');
};
xhReq.send();
```

The response we see in Chrome console is:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http:/xxxx:8093/query/service?statement=select%20member%20from%20`edc`%20where%20member.general_info.member_aces_id=%20%2711111%27. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http:/localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.

From the couchbase documentation I could find online this should work. Please let me know if you want me to include any further configurations. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because Chrome web security won't allow localhost,see http://blog.chromium.org/2010/01/security-in-depth-new-security-features.html for an explanation - try Firefox or override Chrome web security when starting with options:

```
--disable-web-security --user-data-dir
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! We have run with web security disabled but that would not be ideal for a production product. I tried with Firefox and was returned a similar error: 

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://xxxx:8093/query/service?statement=select%20member%20from%20`edc`%20where%20member.general_info.member_aces_id=%20%2711111%27. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).

Comment: Your production users will not be requesting from localhost, so this is only a suggested  workaround for development. I personally develop browser code inside a VM using vagrant and never run into this, but do recall it happening when I ran straight off my localhost in Chrome

Comment: With FireFox i added the addon cors everywhere and enabled it so the response is now:
"errors": [{
            "code": 1120,
            "msg": "Unsupported media type: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"
            } ],
    "status": "fatal"
I am trying to request a JSON doc

Comment: But this is another issue now... maybe just add the reponseType as json e.g. xhReq.responseType('json'); before you hit the send?

Comment: So the solution for this will be to use ajax. I wasn't able to get it done with XMLHttpRequest because of sync/async issues while setting responseType. will post code, thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

While trying to use XMLHttpRequest you cannot set responseType while in asynchronous mode. To avoid this i decided to use ajax like:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://xxxx:8093/query/service?statement=select member from `edc` where member.general_info.member_aces_id='11111'",
    responseType: 'json',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(data) {
      console.log("data: " + JSON.stringify(data));
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, err) {
      console.log("error: " + err + " xhr: " + JSON.stringify(xhr));
    }
  });
```

I also have switched to Firefox from Chrome as chrome does not allow this even with CORS extension. I am using cors everywhere with Firefox as well.